# Androidx EncryptedFile - Best way to write unencrypted File to EncryptedFile

Tags: android, kotlin, filestream

I have an unencrypted File that I want to write as an `EncryptedFile` using the `androidx.security` library. The example docs show reading the existing file to be encrypted into a byte array then writing that byte array to the encrypted file. I worry if the file that needs to be encrypted is very large reading the bytes into memory could cause OOM crashes on older devices. e.g:

```
        val inputStream = FileInputStream(file)
        val bytes = inputStream.readBytes()
        inputStream.close()
        ...

        encryptedFile.openFileOutput().apply {
            write(bytes)
            flush()
            close()
        }
```

Wouldn't opening an input stream and then using the `copyTo` Kotlin extension be the less memory intensive option? Or is there a better way I am overlooking?

```
       encryptedFile.openFileOutput().apply { // opens FileOutputStream
            val inputStream = FileInputStream(file)
            inputStream.copyTo(this)
            inputStream.close()
            flush()
            close()
        }
```

Comment: "Wouldn't opening an input stream and then using the copyTo Kotlin extension be the less memory intensive option?" -- probably yes, though I would use `use()` instead of `apply()` and manual `close()` calls.